# Is ThanetGuide procedurally generated or does this twitter account handwrite microfiction?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, flash-fiction

There is a twitter account called [ThanetGuide](https://twitter.com/ThanetGuide) that posts microfiction in the form of dystopian journal entries.

> diaries of a survivor in post-apocalyptic #thanet, written after the 2025 flooding of the river wantsum. @joebaxterwebb is my dad

Clearly this is science fiction, but it's hard to tell if it's procedurally generated by an algorithm or if each tweet is handwritten (and then perhaps scheduled to give the appearance of being procedural)?

Some examples of 'believably human written' tweets:

> As an ashy cloud set in, I continued following the trail of permanent marker and set off toward Dane Valley.

> Today I walked past an ice cream parlour and saw the place had been decorated in disturbing lipstick scrawlings and swastikas.

> Margate seafront was a mess of poison ivy and old bicycle parts... a vintage Kappa tracksuit hung nearby, soaked with 15p Tesco lemonade.

How is the microfiction written?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Joe Baxter-Webb has [confirmed](https://twitter.com/joebaxterwebb/status/1371093244981968905) these are procedurally generated from smaller snippets.

> It uses “CheapBotsDoneQuick” which means it’s basically a collection of words and phrases that I give it, randomised in a way that is also determined/likited by me. So the tweets aren’t curated but also don’t involve markov chains or any form of machine learning.

> I have a very particular literary-thinking-first approach to creating these sort of bots, which is why they probably come across as more characterful and seemingly “correct” than others.

Answer (score 9):

Joe Baxter-Webb here!

I can give an example of how these work:

> Margate seafront was a mess of poison ivy and old bicycle parts... a vintage Kappa tracksuit hung nearby, soaked with 15p Tesco lemonade.

is generated from the pseudo-template

> [outdoor location] was a mess of [growth type] and [debris type]… [clothing] hung nearby, soaked with [drink].

Those aren’t the real liar/array names in square brackets, but that’s pretty much how it works. The tracery language run by Cheap Bots Done Quick, which Thanet Guide uses, let’s you throw in a tag like #noun# which will then pull a random item from a 2D array called #noun#

Comment: Mind if I move some of the quotes from my answer into yours? Then we'd have one excellent answer and not two great ones?